# Application Insights log: search by Information content

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I want to search Application Insights logs by messages inside. For example, I have the following log:

[image]

I want to search all calls, when message: 'FunctionCallEfsApi no messages' consists...
How can I do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are looking inside *traces* or *exceptions* inside Application Insights, you can use following query to get all messages when message contains : 'FunctionCallEfsApi no messages'

```
traces | where message contains "FunctionCallEfsApi no messages"
```

Answer (score 7):

You can navigate to Logs(Analytics) on Application Insights resource you have and write a query to fetch those information,

```
traces
| where message contains "FunctionCallEfsApi no messages"
```

[image]